# JavaFX silently swallowing exception raised in drag listeners

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

It appears that exceptions are silently swallowed in drag over listeners in JavaFX. I've searched and can't find any mention of this in the documentation.

I've recreated this below...

Is there anyway to prevent this and expose the exceptions?

```
public class App extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button source = new Button("source");
        Button destination = new Button("destination");
        HBox box = new HBox(source, destination);

        source.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
            Dragboard db = source.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.putString("foo");
            db.setContent(content);
            event.consume();
        });
        destination.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.LINK);
                String nullReference = null; 
                nullReference.toCharArray(); // cause an exception
                event.consume();
            }
        });
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(box));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Following feedback from James_D and further investigation, we have found this varies by platform

- Ubuntu Linux. 1.8.0_40 => exceptions seen
- Mac OS X. 1.8.0_40 => exceptions seen
- Windows 7. 1.8.0_40 => No exceptions
- Windows 7. 1.8.0_121 => No exceptions (latest JDK at time of writing)

Comment: If I run that and drag over the `destination`, I see plenty of beautiful stack traces in my console....

Comment: I tested on Mac OS X with JDK 1.8.0_121.

Comment: I just tried on Ubuntu 16.04 / 1.8.0_40... and I get traces... Looks like they're rooted from different class though.... " at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)"... must be Windows implementation that is swallowing.. but not Linux / OS X...

Comment: Full drag-and-drop interacts with the native OS (because it allows dragging and dropping externally from/to the application), so I can believe this is platform-dependent. I would check with a more recent JDK release though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that native method `WinDnDClipboard.push(Object[], int)` - backed by [GlassClipboard.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/tip/modules/graphics/src/main/native-glass/win/GlassClipboard.cpp) swallows the exception silently. A call back to Throwable.getMessage() can be seen in the debugger but no exception is printed to the console.

The Java 9 version of this file (http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9-dev/rt/file/1a3f128518cd/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/native-glass/win/GlassClipboard.cpp) has an additional call to `CheckAndClearException(env);` as defined in Utils.cpp, however this is against RT-35400 which appears unrelated. This has not been backported to Java 8.

Comment: did you file a bug report for this I can vote on? Same issue with Java 10 and win 10